# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre el GroupLayout y el AbsoluteLayout?

Tags: java, layout, netbeans-absolutelayout

Encontre hace poco el grouplayout y tengo entendido que se hizo para el desarrollo con la herramienta de netbeans.El tema es que no se que diferencia puede tener con el absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ventaja de definir una distribución AbsoluteLayout es la facilidad para colocar cada elemento en la ventana (no tendrás los problemas del Diseño Libre). Sin embargo, la desventaja es que los elementos no mantienen una distribución relativa respecto al tamaño de la ventana.

Mientras que GroupLayout Consiste en una ventana que muestra un botón que cambia de tamaño conforme se redimenziona el contenedor de la ventana.

El GroupLayout destaca entre los demás administradores de despliegue porque nos permite establecer de manera precisa la posición y el tamaño de cada componente dentro del contenedor.

Comment: Ahhh perfecto,o sea que el grouplayout cumple con la funcion normal de todos los layout de redimensionar el componente segun se estire la ventana y ademas dejando elegir la posicion en la cual nosotros queramos añadir el componente?

Comment: Es correcto @SantiagoSalinas